# how to make a clock like this?

Tags: digital-logic, clock, flipflop

Could someone help me to make a clock that has outputs like this

[image]


there are 3 clock outputs 


I have a reference schematic here, and this clock has 4 output and it made up of 2 flip flops, it uses IC SN74LS74 as shown in the picture, the IC is used to divide the frequency by 4 and then it is possible to use those states using logic gates to give the correct output
[image]


So I need the output are just 3 clocks, could someone help me to find a true states for this problem.

Comment: Do the three clock pulses need to be strictly non-overlapping?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a decade counter like [(74HC)4017](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheets/320/499984_DS.pdf)? You use a single clock signal for input and you connect the first unused output to \$\overline{\text{RESET}}\$

[image]

So in your case you would connect "Decoded output 4" to \$\overline{\text{RESET}}\$ and use "Decoded output 0, 1 and 2" as output. The clock input must be four times higher than the desired output.

Comment: @DaveTweed OK, so he has to loop back ouput 4 to \$\overline{\text{RESET}}\$.

Comment: The problem to be solved has only 3 states, you should undo your edit.  See the first waveform diagram.

Comment: @rawbrawb Actually the clock diagram in the question is not entirely clear about what happens after third clock pulse. I think/hope OP catches the idea.

Comment: @jippie thank you for answering my qustion, i can understand your idea so far, but my question is can this IC divide the frequency by 3 before it provide outputs shown in first picture in my question ?

Comment: Look at the timing diagram. Your clock is all the way up and the respective outputs are numbered 0-9. To shorten the sequence you connect the first unused pin to reset.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a home work question - so here are some hints:

This is three state system, so at the least you can use 2 FF's (for a maximum of 4 states) and throw logic to sequence through each of the three states and avoid the 4th state.  Or you can use 3 FF's and simplify the logic (i.e. that sequence just looks like a shift register propagating a pulse).

Comment: There are four distinct states in the OP's diagram.

Comment: @DaveTweed 3 separate NOC's is three states NOT 4 see first waveform diagram.  The 2nd schematic diagram is an example that he was wondering if he could modify and that does have 4 states.

Comment: The **four** states are 100, 010, 001 and 000, and then the sequence (presumably) repeats.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm assuming he just sketched it up quickly and dropped the repeat.  It would be unusual but as posed ...

Comment: @DaveTweed maybe he just wants a one shot on each LOL

Comment: Why the -1? It looks exactly like a homework question.